# To Fetch Row data fully from FirebaseRealtime-database by checking the product id (child id) with android app scan result id

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

my app is with barcode scanner and i have created Firebase Realtime-database for the app. i entered some data to database. i want to fetch all the data(name,details,price) in a row by checking the scanresult to the id(in a specific row) in the database. found some tutorials similar to query but i couldn't set code as i wish. please, anyone help me to do this small correction for me ?

below i mentioned my present working code. but it is checking the scanresult with the row unique id and fetched as i want to do. but it is difficult to enter the data with same UID as same as scanresult. This code is working only when i dynamically add data directly to database in site.

The first pic is, of working present code:

[image]

the secong pic is to be fetch by checking its id :

[image]

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    final String scanResult = result.getText().toString();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);


    databasefetch = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("save").child(scanResult);
    databasefetch.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
            String details = dataSnapshot.child("details").getValue().toString();
            String price = dataSnapshot.child("price").getValue().toString();

            text.setText("\nProduct Name : "+name+"\nDetails : "+details+"\nPrice : "+price);

            //text to speech
            String  toSpeak=text.getText().toString();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),toSpeak,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            txt.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the data from the second JSON snippet based on its `id` property, you need to run a query:

```
databasefetch = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("save");
Query query = databasefetch.orderByChild("id").equalTo(8901058862836L);
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        String name = snapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
        String details = snapshot.child("details").getValue(String.class);
        String price = snapshot.child("price").getValue(String.class);

        ...
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
})
```

Comment: van prffelen, sir the textview is still blank

Comment: and the scanresult is of 13 digit number so did that cause error on fetching? because the number i wrote directly to " .equalTo(8901058862836); " that shows " integer number too large" and shows error in android studio. is it so?

Comment: i want to place the scanresult directly to the " .equalTo(8901058862836); " as " .equalTo(scanResult); ". will that cause a typecast error on running (but android studio does not show the error right now). is n't it ?

Comment: If the number is too large for an integer, use a `Long`. I updated the code in my answer to add an `L` at the end of the numeric literal. But if it's in a `Long` or `long` variable that'd be the same.

Comment: sir, you are correct. It worked as i wish but i want to place that number as "scanResult". when i add "L" to this number it shows error (i wrote like this .equalTo(scanResultL) how it possible). when i write the number it fetches correctly with L.

Comment: i separately converted the scanresult datatype string to Long as                   
 
        final String scanResult = result.getText().toString();
        long l = Long.parseLong(scanResult);
       databasefetch = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("save");
        Query query = databasefetch.orderByChild("id").equalTo(l);                          and put the 'l' to the query as .equalTo(l);   code worked as i mentioned thank you very much sir. it was a part of my android project. and May God bless you always......